# Cross Domain in Tomcat using crossdomain.xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to add another page in my web pages. My first choice is iframe, but the target websites didn't allow iframe. After that I tried using cross domain. I'm using tomcat 7.0.27

I place my crossdomain.xml in webapps/ROOT/crossdomain.xml

My crossdomain.xml code:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
> <cross-domain-policy>
> <allow-access-from domain="*" />
> </cross-domain-policy>
> ```

my jsp code:

> ```
> <html>
> <head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script></head>
> <body>
> <script>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   jQuery('#result').load('http://www.facebook.com', function() {
>       alert('Load was performed.');
>   });
>   });
> </script>
> <div id="result"/>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

The problem is it still doesn't work. I got an error says

```
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.facebook.com/. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**
```

What I miss?

Comment: Getting Javascript to load content from another domain is nothing to do with the server, it's the client which is not allowing it for security reasons.

Comment: so i can't tell the browser client something like "hey, it's okay. I trust this website."?